# linux module mutual function reference

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel

I'm developing two different linux kernel module (module A, module B).

module A uses module B's function
Actually, it is clear for me using extern_symbol and module.symvers.

but i wanna know how to handle that case module A uses module B's function and at the same time module B uses module A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a third kernel module (or statically compiled), which will export the functions used by both modules which will be stubs till both modules load - then, each module will register its callbacks.

**Code sample**

module integration

```
static int func1(int x);
static int func2(int y);

int xxx_func1(int x)
{
     if (func1)
         return func1(x);
     return -EPERM;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(xxx_func1);

int xxx_func2(int x)
{
     if (func2)
         return func2(x);
     return -EPERM;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(xxx_func2);

int xxx_register_func(int id, int (*func)(int))
{
     if (id == 1)
          func1 = func;
     else if (id ==2)
          func2 = func;

     return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(xxx_register_func);

int xxx_unregister_func(int id)
{
     if (id == 1)
          func1 = NULL;
     else if (id ==2)
          func2 = NULL;

     return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(xxx_unregister_func);
```

module 1

```
static int module1_func1(int x)
{
    ...
}

static int module1_do_something(...)
{
    ...
    xxx_func2(123);
    ...
}

static int module1_probe(...)
{
     ...
     xxx_register_func(1, module1_func1);
     ...
}
```

And the same for module2...

Of course you should add mutex to guard the function registration, handle edge cases, etc.

Comment: Thank you, It is answer I really want!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Modules load one at a time, and all symbols have to be resolved when you load a module, so a pair of modules which referenced symbols in each other would be impossible to load.

Find some way to structure these modules that avoids the circular references.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.